# Unable to post message to http://domain.com. Recipient has origin https://www.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, authentication

Sorry if this has already been asked but I couldn't find it when searching.

The "Login with Facebook" function was working for me previously, but now when I or anyone else tries to use it initially to ALLOW the app, it fails. It freezes just after accepting to login at this URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request

I opened up the Chrome console and it displays this error: "Unable to post message to [DOMAIN]. Recipient has origin https://www.facebook.com."

However, if I just close the window and proceed to try again, it logs me in successfully.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks for your time,
~Josh.